# try with subsequent try, or try with subsequent if

Tags: python, pyramid

I've read up on the differences between `try` and `if`, but what about after?

Suppose the following:

```
try:
    email = request.GET['email']
except KeyError:
    email = None
```

Then what? What's more *pythonic* and/or efficient?

```
if email is None:
     ...
```

or

```
try:
    dostuffwithemail(email)
```

As with most things python, I suppose it depends. In my case, it seems like it would be better (efficient) to use `if`. The *look before you leap* mentality fits here, because if email contains something, it needs to do a fair bit. otherwise, it doesn't/shouldn't do anything. It seems less efficient to do something if it knows it's going to fail.

Thoughts?

Edit from comments:

If I'm understanding the flow correctly, seems this would be more efficient:

```
try:
    email = request.GET['email']
except KeyError:
    return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('home'))
dostuffwithemail(email)
```

The end result of the page would eventually return data from `dostuffwithemail` (ie, check email against a db), and then allow a user to submit a form. If email isnt there, it returns the user back to `home`

Comment: How far will `dostuffwithemail` get on `None`? You could put the call into the `else` block of the `try`, instead, but I would say that `if email is not None` is the way to go here.

Comment: Who is responsible for handling the case when email is None? You could shorten the first snippet to `email = request.GET.get('email', None)`

Comment: `dostuffwithemail` is more an example than anything. Realistically, if I'm using `if`, there would be a moderate amount of code following inside in the `if`. Not sure as its such a great idea to have a lot of code inside a `try`, especially other `try`s or `if`s

Comment: Hum. What needs to happen if `email is None`?

Comment: It entirely depends on whether or not you can keep going once this happens. If there's something that can be done, by all means carry on. Otherwise, your `try` block should contain most of the logic or else the `except` block should end the program with an explanation of the error.

Comment: if `email is None`, since it's a pyramid page, the page's main function wouldn't do anything, so it would `return HTTPFound` to another page.

Comment: then I'd be inclined to do `try: email = request.GET['email']; except KeyError: return HTTPFound`

Comment: @JeremyDavis Your edited in code at the end looks like your best bet. Please edit it out of the question and post it instead as an answer to the question, as it will be useful to other users who later find this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, the best way is something like:

```
try:
    email = request.GET['email']
    dostuffwithemail(email)
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Comment: I would be inclined towards moving `dostuffwithemail` to an `else` block, so that any `KeyError` that it raises that we *weren't* expecting gets seen.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case it may be better, contrary to the Pyhton's [EAFP mantra](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html), to "ask for permission" first. At least, I think the following is shorter, more readable and better conveys the programmer's intent:

```
if 'email' in request.GET:
    do_stuff_with_email(request.GET['email'])
else:
    do_stuff_when_email_is_missing()
```